# Почему некоторые имена недоступны в std?

Tags: c++, namespace

Почему большинство имён стандартной библиотеки доступны с помощью `std::`, а  для некоторых нужно указывать дополнительные пространства? Например, `std::chrono::` и `std::filesystem::`.

Comment: А откуда вообще возник такой вопрос? Само пространство `std` создали для того, чтобы не захламлять/не перегружать глобальное пространство имен. Естественно, что та же самая проблема может возникнуть и внутри самого `std` и там внутри решается она так же.

Answer (score 2):

`std` - это пространство имён стандартной библиотеки, `filesystem` тоже пространство имён и находится внутри `std`. Такая иерархия сделана, потому все функции и классы стандарта используют пространство `std`, а `filesystem` и `std` имеют функции с одинаковыми названиями, но совершенно разной разной областью и логикой работы, и чтобы их не перемешивать, то функции работы с файловой системой вынесли в отдельное пространство имён `filesystem`. Или просто логически отделить функции и классы некоторой области работы в одно пространство имён, даже если они не имеют пересечений с std.

Можно сокращать префикс:

```
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
fs::path p1 = "C:\\file";
```